# Error C2664 While Building Surge XT Python Bindings

Tags: python, audio, cmake

I am trying to build Surge XT synthesizer with python bindings so that I can use surge methodically. I have been following the instructions at [Surge's GitHub Page](https://github.com/surge-synthesizer/surge?tab=readme-ov-file), so I ran

```
git clone https://github.com/surge-synthesizer/surge.git
cd surge
git submodule update --init --recursive
cmake -Bbuild
cmake --build build --config Release --target surge-staged-assets
```

and then ran

```
cmake -Bignore/bpy -DSURGE_BUILD_PYTHON_BINDINGS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

The last one didn't have and on the GitHub page, and it was throwing an error, so I changed it to on and it seems to have worked, but it could be causing the error later. I then ran

```
cmake --build ignore/bpy --parallel --target surgepy
```

which after building some other files threw the error C2664,

```
cannot convert argument 3 from const std::filesystem::path::value_type * to const char *.
```

How do I fix this error? I'm not very familiar with c++ or cmake.